# What is the difference between A.length and A.heap-size?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, heap

I have a question about heap sort. It state in an Algorithms book that `A.heap-size<= A.length`
I don’t understand the difference between the two. If an array represents a heap, why is there a possibility that `A.heap-size` is less than `A.length`. I know that `A.heap-size` represents the number of elements inside a heap, so why is it not completely only equal to the number of items inside an array?

Comment: It sounds like your book's implementation of heap sort uses the first "section" of the array for the heap, and the second "section" of the array for the sorted elements. The heap starts with `A.length` elements, but as you remove the max element... the heap shrinks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After k iterations of the outer loop of heap sort, the array consists of an n−k element max heap on the n−k smallest elements (A.heap-size = n−k) followed by the k largest elements in sorted order (A.length = n).

Comment: could you be more specific ? I couldnt understand the difference

Answer (score 9):

Just to expand an answer. Read further that book.

`A.heap_size` of an array, is that place where heap (max_heap or min_heap) structure elements will be placed. It makes sense in scope of sorting or queuing. You are right: this is the number of elements inside a heap, but it's equal to `A.length` only at **first iteration** of heap sort.

At next iteration, after exchanging root of the max_heap tree (`A[1]`) with `A[i] = A[A.length]` (last element inside array A), the `A[1]` element will be the last element of the A, and `A.heap_sort` value will be decreased by 1 and max_heap structure should be max_heapified: `A[Parent(i)] >= A[i]`, where `Parent(i)` returns i/2 of heap tree.

Answer (score 3):

From Cormen's Algorithm textbook which I'm using:
(this helped me)
[image]

Comment: In a heap why is the root node A[1] and not A[0]? Also, if A[1] is the root, what is A[0]?

Comment: the heap has to be represented as a 1-indexed array instead of 0 indexed since the arithmetic you do in order to get the children and parents makes more sense that way.

The left child of node i will always be node 2i.
The right child of node i will be node 2i+1.
This tells you that the parent node of node i is floor(i/2).

This gives 1 for node 1, but 1 for node 2 which isn't right since if node 0 is the root, we'd want 1 and 2 to be its children.

Answer (score 0):

A.length gives the total no of elements of array whereas A.heap size given the no of elements which are in sorted order or no of elements which are following the heap property........And A.length-A.heap size or even not sorted even now and has to be sort in future.