# Difference between A.heapsize and A.length for an array A with an example

Tags: algorithm

Can some one please explain the difference between A.heapsize and A.length for an Array A with the help of an example.

Found a related thread([What is the difference between A.length and A.heap-size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059806/what-is-the-difference-between-a-length-and-a-heap-size)) but was not able to get the difference, is the difference specific to heap sort or is it in general for all heaps.

Comment: In case of HeapSort we usually decrease our heapsize by eleminating highest/Lowest element in heap. So array size is fixed but heapsize is decreasing...

Comment: So ,for a binary heap(when we are not talking about sorting) A.heapsize= A.length ,always.?

Comment: Yes you can say if you took whole array as Binary Heap means I can build heap inside array also of size k < n(size of array).

Answer (score 0):

You can think that your array is a container and that your heap is the amount of resources you have. In languages like C++ (and in general), arrays will start at a default value like a 100 elements. Once you use all the available space, the compiler will create a new array twice the size of your original.

Meaning: Your heap might have 10 nodes but your array will have the capacity of a 100. I would suggest looking at C++ vector `size` vs `capacity`.